# Replace two consecutive special characters with space

Tags: python

I am trying to replace occurrence of two consecutive special characters with space for that i have written below code but i am not getting proper result.

Code:

```
import re
text = "08391@#AP@#RETSEHC@#TSEW@#TS@#ELDDIB@#E@#163"
deciphername = ciphername[::-1]
deciphername.replace("@#"," ")
```

Output:

> '361 E BIDDLE ST\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbdWEST
>   CHESTER\xef\xbf\xbdPA\xef\xbf\xbd19380'

Expected Output:

> 361 E BIDDLE ST WEST CHESTER PA 19380

What i am doing wrong ?

Comment: Strings are immutable, `replace` does not replace in-place. Use `deciphername = deciphername.replace("@#"," ")`. When this is fixed, your `replace` works fine. Also, no need to `import re` if you only use `str.replace`.

Comment: what is `ciphername[::-1]` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest it reverses my string.

Comment: @tobias_k is correct but you also inverted the order of the replace if you notice the pound sign comes first so it should be `('#@', ' ')`

Comment: @tobias_k Thanks for the solution. It worked.